# render multiple suffixes with one template engine in spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, templates, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I created two thymleaf resolvers and added them to a template engine, so I can process txt/svg templates in spring-boot.

```
@Configuration
public class TemplateEngineConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine textTemplateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(textTemplateResolver());
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(svgTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver textTemplateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setOrder(1);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".txt");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver svgTemplateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setOrder(2);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".svg");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

I use it like this.

```
@Component
public class TemplateRenderer {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("textTemplateEngine")
    private TemplateEngine textTemplateEngine;

    public String renderPlainText(String filename, Map<String, Object> params) {
        Context context = new Context(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale(), params);
        return textTemplateEngine.process(filename, context);
    }

}
```

It didn't work. I tried to render `templates/img.svg`, but Thymleaf complained that it couldn't find `templates/img.txt` file, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Just force your SpringTemplateEngine to check for the existence of the templates and not only use the defined patterns. Please force that by adding

```
templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);
```

to each of your template resolvers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should marked ITemplateResolver with @bean and Qualifier so when 
you will @autowire textTemplateEngine or svgTemplateEngine so spring will autowire them with Qualifier name.

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("textTemplateEngine")
private ITemplateResolver textTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setOrder(1);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".txt");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("svgTemplateEngine")
private ITemplateResolver svgTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setOrder(2);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".svg");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return templateResolver;
}
```

Also you can configure Thymeleaf multiple resolvers by xml config like:

```
<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
  <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
  <property name="templateEngine">
    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
      <property name="dialects">
        <set>
          <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.dialect.SpringStandardDialect" />
        </set>
      </property>
      <property name="templateResolvers">
        <set>
          <bean class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
            <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
            <property name="prefix" value="/fragments/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
            <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
          </bean>
          <bean class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
            <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
            <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
            <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
          </bean>
        </set>
      </property>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```